# Problem about partial different equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve partial differential equation :

$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-a^2u_{xx}+bu=f(x,t), 0<x<L, t>0 \\
u_x(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=0, t \geq 0 \\
u(x,0)=u_0(x),u_t(x,0)=u_1(x), 0 \le x \le L
\end{cases}
$$

I'm starting to learn about pde, and i having this problem. Could someone tell me what kind of equation it is? And the idea to solve it. I see its form is almost the same as the wave equation but i have no idea to solve it. Thanks very much.

Comment: Looks like an inhomogeneous wave equation

Comment: kind : hyperbolic problem. but what do you mean by solving?

Comment: Letting $u = e^{\sqrt{b}/a}v(x,t)$ will turn the equation into a forced wave equation. Your initial conditions will change slightly, but it’s okay, because of the RHS, we can apply a eigenfunction expansion trick to get around it.